# How calculate variance remaining energy vs node in ns2?

Tags: ns2

I can get the reaming energy node in ns2 but I'd like to plot variance remaining energy vs nodes? how can I do it?
I know how should I calculate variance but I don't know how use it in this scenario?

best regards to you

Comment: Google  https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+calculate+variance+remaining+energy **:::**  https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_be_aware_of_the_remaining_energy_of_nodes_in_NS2 → → https://www.researchgate.net/deref/http%3A%2F%2Felmurod.net%2Fen%2Findex.php%2Farchives%2F348

Comment: thanks, @kund but it about gets the remaining energy of nodes not about how to calculate variance please read my question first carefully thanks again.